# WebAPI и winforms

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Есть сайт на ASP.Net Core 7. В нём есть Api-контроллер для получения информации о пользователе

```
[HttpGet("{value}"), ItemCanBeNull]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get ([FromBody, NotNull] string value)
{
    //Создаю результат
    APILoginResult result = new();

    APILogin model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APILogin>(value);

    //Здесь получаю пользователя

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

и есть консольное приложение (пока для теста, а потом в WinForms) с методом получения данных:

```
//Http клиент
HttpClient client = new();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44304/api/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
await LoginAsync(client);
```

и вот собственно сама функция:

```
static async Task LoginAsync (HttpClient client)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите имя пользователя:");
    string? userName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Введите пароль пользователя:");
    string userPassword = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    APILogin model = new()
    {
        Login = userName ?? "user",
        Password = userPassword,
        DeviceId = "1231"
    };

    string value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

    // определяем данные запроса
    using HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Get, $"https://localhost:44304/api/account/");

    StringContent requestContent = new(value, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    request.Content = requestContent;

    // получаем ответ
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    // просматриваем данные ответа
    // статус
    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.StatusCode}\n");
    //заголовки
    Console.WriteLine("Headers");
    foreach (var header in response.Headers)
    {
        Console.Write($"{header.Key}:");
        foreach (var headerValue in header.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(headerValue);
        }
    }
    // содержимое ответа
    Console.WriteLine("\nContent");
    string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

Проблема: выводит, что страница не найдена. Вопрос: всё ли корректно или что-то не так? Подскажите, где можно копать инфу КАК ОРГАНИЗОВАТЬ это дело.

Comment: Единственное чего добился, это получения ошибки Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "{"IsSuccess":false,"ErrorMessage":"Попытка входа в систему пользователя неуспешна! Проверьте имя пользователя и пароль!","User":null}" to type 'APILoginResult'. Path '', line 1, position 143.

Comment: Как ни странно, помогло удаление кода:Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        //Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать следующим способом.

**API Controller**

```
[HttpGet, ItemCanBeNull]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get ([CanBeNull] string value)
{
    //Создаю результат
    APILoginResult result = new() {IsSuccess = false};
    if (value == null)
    {
        //Вывожу ошибку
        result.ErrorMessage = "Нет данных для входа пользователя!";
        //Вывожу результат
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    }
    //Получаю модель
    APILogin model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APILogin>(value);
    //... ТУТ ПОЛУЧАЮ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕЙ
    //Возвращаю результат
    result.IsSuccess = true;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

**Статический класс**

```
public static class APIActions
{
    //Http клиент
    private static readonly HttpClient Client;

    //Http клиент
    private const string BaseUrl = "https://example.com/api";

    /// <summary>
    /// Конструктор
    /// </summary>
    static APIActions () => Client = new();

    public static async Task<APILoginResult> LoginAsync (string userName, string userPassword)
    {
        //Создаю модель входа
        APILogin model = new()
        {
            Login = userName,
            Password = userPassword
        };

        //Получаю адрес url
        string url = $"{BaseUrl}/account?value={JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)}";

        //Задаём данные запроса
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Get, url);

        //Посылаем запрос и записываем ответ
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.SendAsync(request);

        //Получаю содержимое
        await using Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        string content = await new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEndAsync();
        content = content.Trim();

        //Вывожу результат
        return
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APILoginResult>(content,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore

                })
            ?? new();
    }
}
```

**Консольное приложение**

```
static async Task LoginAsync ()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите имя пользователя:");
    string? userName = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    Console.WriteLine("Введите пароль пользователя:");
    string userPassword = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

    APILoginResult result = await APIActions.LoginAsync(userName, userPassword);

    if (!result.IsSuccess)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorMessage);
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Получена информация о пользователе:");
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
}
```

В целом, теперь работает.